# ObjectListview extremely slow on textbased filter and rebind

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I am having serious speed issues with ef6 and object list view specifically when a text filter is applied. When I dont have one on everything is fine.

```
private void FilterJobs()
{
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        if (jobsFilterTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            jobsList.ModelFilter = new TextMatchFilter(jobsList, jobsFilterTextBox.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            jobsFilterButton.Enabled = false;
            jobsClearFilterButton.Enabled = true;
            jobsFilterLabel.Text = string.Format("{0} of {1} records", jobsList.Items.Count, ((System.Collections.ArrayList)jobsList.Objects).Count);

        }
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
 }
```

I am setting my jobs list to be that with the following method.

```
private void BindJobs()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Job> jobs = null;

            if (showLiveJobsOnlyCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                jobs = new JobRepository(new UnitOfWork()).Find(x => x.JobStatusID != (int) JobStatusEnum.Cancelled && x.JobStatusID != (int) JobStatusEnum.Complete).OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                jobs = new JobRepository(new UnitOfWork()).GetAll().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).ToList();
            }

             jobsList.LoadObjects(jobs);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionManager.HandleUnexpectedException(ex);
        }
  }
```

The following is my find method from the above method and my getall method.

```
 public override IQueryable<Job> Find(Expression<Func<Job, bool>> predicate)
 {
        return DbSet
            .Include(x => x.JobLines).AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.Customer).AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.SysCurrency).AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.JobStatus).AsNoTracking()
            .Where(predicate);
}
```

My Getall method.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
{
        return DbSet.AsNoTracking().AsEnumerable().ToList();
}
```

As you see I added asnotracking in the hope that it would speed it up and initial load is fast but when the user select the section to show Live jobs only but with the customer name still in the filter its painfully slow.

**Edit 2**

This is showing me using the performance pro filler which lead me to these functions which are called from the checked changed event.

[image]

**Edit 3**

To show my load objects methods.

```
public static void LoadObjects(this ObjectListView objectListView, IEnumerable objects)
{
        Form form = objectListView.FindForm();

        try
        {
            if (form != null)
                form.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            objectListView.BeginUpdate();
            objectListView.ClearObjects();
            objectListView.SetObjects(objects);
        }
        finally 
        {
            objectListView.EndUpdate();

            if (form != null)
                form.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Do you use a VS version that supports the "Performance profiler"? Maybe that would be an option to locate the bottleneck.

Comment: I check that and it is on the bind jobs method which i exepected.

Comment: How many items do you have? A text filter is probably pretty slow per se. What is LoadObjects(), its not a standard method of the OLV or is it?

Comment: Its only 8 thousand records bare with me will show you now.

Comment: @Rev1.0 please see edit 3 above.

Comment: I did respond to your message on SourceForge: https://sourceforge.net/p/objectlistview/discussion/812922/thread/66962202a1/. 

Your control has 8000 rows and took 2.3 seconds to load. That is ~0.25ms per row. What sort of performance were you expecting?